# Convert nested list to list-of-lists with a depth of 1

Tags: python, list, recursion

I have lists of the following form:

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12]]]]]
```

These lists can be of varying "depth" and can have a varying number of elements at each level (i.e. the outer list can have a different number of elements than its inner).

How can I convert this into a list of lists with a depth of 1:

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

Comment: Is an inner list always the last element of the outer list?

Comment: @fafl it is a different problem.

Comment: @fafl it is important for me to keep the structure of the lists, just make them all have the same depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a recursive approach:

```
def listOfList(lst):
    b = []
    def recurs(lst):
        c = []
        for i in lst:
            if isinstance(i, list):
                if c:
                    b.append(c)
                    c = []
                recurs(i)
            else:
                c.append(i)
        if c: b.append(c)
        return b
    return recurs(lst)
```

Example:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12]]]]]
>>> listOfList(a)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
>>> a = [[[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14]]]]]]]
>>> listOfList(a)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14]]
```

This is also useful in case the list is not nested in proper way:

```
>>> a = [[[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14]]]]]], [15, 16]]
>>> listOfList(a)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16]]
>>> a = [[[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14]]]]]], [15, 16], 17, 18, 19]
>>> listOfList(a)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16], [17, 18, 19]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, 7, [8, 9, [10, 11, 12]]]]]
new_a = []
while isinstance(a, list):
    last = a.pop()
    if a:
        new_a.append(a)
    a = last
print(new_a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need a recursion to ergodic your nested list.

```
def func(c):
    d = []
    if isinstance(c[-1], list):
        return [c[:-1], *func(c[-1])]
    else:
        return [c]
print(func(a))
```

And the output is:

```
>>> [[], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

There is a empty list at first because the top level of your lists only have one item. To convert it as you want, you can use another for loop:

```
for b in a:
    print(func(b))
```

Then the result is what you want:

```
>>> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```